# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.00\n'

Tags: python, tesseract, pyautogui, python-tesseract

I'm using pyautogui to take a printout of a price, and pytesseract to turn that printout into a string. I need to know if this number is < or > than 100, but when I send to print my variable, I get only a number, and when I send print int(variable) I have: variable + \n;
For example:

```
x = 10
print(x) = 10
print int(x) = 10\n
```

code:

```
im1 = p.screenshot(region=(280,951, 85, 25))
   im1.save(r"C:\Users\Ball\Desktop\notas\peçaspreço.png")
   preço1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('peçaspreço.png'))
   print (preço1)
   if (int(preço1) > 100:
```

error and "print (preço1)":

```
20.00

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ball\Desktop\notas\Nota.py", line 62, in <module>
    produto()
  File "C:\Users\Ball\Desktop\notas\Nota.py", line 28, in produto
    if int(preço1) > 100:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.00\n'
```

Comment: Thx!!! I was close to giving up

Answer (score 1):

The newline is not the problem:

```
>>> int('20\n')
10
```

The decimal point is:

```
>>> int('20.00')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.00'
```

You need to parse it as a `float` first, then pass the resulting `float` to `int`:

```
>>> int(float('20.00\n'))
20
```

This may have its own problems, for example if the number is so large that it cannot be accurately represented as a `float`, even if it is "really" an integer. Compare

```
>>> int(10000000000000000000000.0)
10000000000000000000000
```

with

```
>>> int(100000000000000000000000.0)
99999999999999991611392
```